# AT NEW with substring access?

Tags: loops, substring, abap

I have a solution that includes a LOOP which I would like to spare. So I wonder, whether you know a better way to do this.

My goal is to loop through an internal, alphabetically sorted standard table. This table has two columns: a name and a table, let's call it subtable. For every subtable I want to do some stuff (open an xml page in my xml framework).

Now, every subtable has a corresponding name. I want to group the subtables according to the first letter of this name (meaning, put the pages of these subtables on one main page -one main page for every character-). By grouping of subtables I mean, while looping through the table, I want to deal with the subtables differently according to the first letter of their name.

So far I came up with the following solution:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF l_str_tables_extra,
        first_letter(1) TYPE c,
        name TYPE string,
        subtable TYPE REF TO if_table,
       END OF l_str_tables_extra.

DATA: ls_tables_extra TYPE l_str_tables_extra.
DATA: lt_tables_extra TYPE TABLE OF l_str_tables_extra.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_tables> TYPE str_table."Like LINE OF lt_tables.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_tables_extra> TYPE l_str_tables_extra.


*"--- PROCESSING LOGIC ------------------------------------------------
SORT lt_tables ASCENDING BY name.

"Add first letter column in order to use 'at new' later on
"This is the loop I would like to spare
LOOP AT lt_tables ASSIGNING <ls_tables>.
  ls_tables_extra-first_letter = <ls_tables>-name+0(1). "new column
  ls_tables_extra-name = <ls_tables>-name.
  ls_tables_extra-subtable = <ls_tables>-subtable.
 APPEND ls_tables_extra TO lt_tables_extra.
ENDLOOP.

LOOP AT lt_tables_extra ASSIGNING <ls_tables_extra>.
 AT NEW first_letter.
  "Do something with subtables with same first_letter.
 ENDAT.
ENDLOOP.
```

I wish I could use

```
 AT NEW name+0(1)
```

instead of

```
AT NEW first_letter
```

, but offsets and lengths are not allowed.

You see, I have to inlcude this first loop to add another column to my table which is kind of unnecessary because there is no new info gained.

In addition, I am interested in other solutions because I get into trouble with the framework later on for different reasons. A different way to do this might help me out there, too.

I am happy to hear any thoughts about this! I could not find anything related to this here on stackoverflow, but I might have used not optimal search terms ;)

Comment: Which NetWeaver version are you using?

Comment: I use SAP Logon 750.

Comment: The SAP Logon version is irrelevant, we need the SAP_BASIS  / SAP_ABA version (system --> status)

Comment: Component version is SAP SOLUTION MANAGER 7.1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not using a IF comparison?

```
data: lf_prev_first_letter(1) type c.

loop at lt_table assigning <ls_table>.
    if <ls_table>-name(1) <> lf_prev_first_letter. "=AT NEW
       "do something
       lf_prev_first_letter = <ls_table>-name(1).
    endif.
endloop.
```

Comment: I don't know why not!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the `GROUP BY` addition on `LOOP` could help you in this case:

```
LOOP AT i_tables
  INTO DATA(wa_line)
  " group lines by condition
  GROUP BY (
    " substring() because normal offset would be evaluated immediately
    name = substring( val = wa_line-name len = 1 )
  ) INTO DATA(o_group).

  " begin of loop over all tables starting with o_group-name(1)

  " loop over group object which contains 
  LOOP AT GROUP o_group
    ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_table>).
      " <fs_table> contains your table
  ENDLOOP.

  " end of loop

ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Thanks. Yet, I think the 'group by' works only together with 'select' for data bases. But I am interested in an internal table. Am I wrong?
It has the advantage to not to have to declare an additional type. But is another loop nevertheless.

Comment: @Ela `GROUP BY`  is also valid syntax on `LOOP` and works as I proposed in my answer. At least on NetWeaver >7.4